# How to get cumulative total for previous month and upto this month?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, greatest-n-per-group

```
ID  pcID    contractor  approver    claimed
-------------------------------------------
1   1       one          1000         900
2   1       two          200          100
3   1       three        1000        1000
4   1       six          100          11
5   2       six          100          22
6   3       six          120           1
7   4       three        102          10
```

From the above table, I need to get cumulative amount for upto this month and previous month of approver and claimed and also current month approver, claimed amount based on the contractor. Like below table.

```
ID  contractor  approver    claimed  uptothisMTApprover   uptothisMTClaimed  previousMTApprover previousMTClaimed 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    one          1000       900     1000                 900                0                   0
2    two          200        100     200                  100                0                   0
3    three        102        10      1102                 1010               1000                1000
4    six          120        1       320                  34                 200                 33
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: And what is *a month* in your data?

Comment: pcID is denote the month(payment certificate released each month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the latest row per `contractor`, as defined by `pcID`, and a cumulative sum of all previous months.

You can use window functions:

```
select contractor, approver, claimed, 
    total_approver            as uptothisMTApprover, 
    total_claimed             as uptothisMTClaimed,
    total_approver - approver as previousMTApprover, 
    total_claimed  - claimed  as previousMTClaimed
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number()  over(partition by contractor order by pcID desc) rn,
        sum(approver) over(partition by contractor) total_approver,
        sum(claimed)  over(partition by contractor) total_claimed
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: approver and claimed column are current month amount data. Can you help me in that

Comment: @keerthiseelan: the window function had the wrong sort order... Fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time spending for me.